# std::bad_array_new_length for large numbers

Tags: c++

I try to run following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int find_next(int act, unsigned long long survivors[], int n)
{
    int i = act;
    while (survivors[i] == 0)
    {
        i++;
        i = i % n;
    }
    i = (i + 1) % n; // found first one, but need to skip 
    while (survivors[i] == 0)
    {
        i++;
        i = i % n;

    }// thats the guy 
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    long long int lines;
    long long int* results;

    scanf_s("%llu", &lines);
    results = new long long int[lines];

    for (long long int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        unsigned long long n, k;

        scanf_s("%llu", &n);
        scanf_s("%llu", &k);
        unsigned long long* survivors;
        survivors = new unsigned long long[n];
        for (int m = 0; m < n; m++) {
            survivors[m] = 1;
        }
        int* order;
        order = new int[n];
        int p = 0;
        int act = 0;
        while (p < n - 1)
        {
            act = find_next(act, survivors, n);
            order[p] = act;
            survivors[act] = 0; // dies; 
            p++;
        }
        order[p] = find_next(act, survivors, n);

        if (k > 0)
        {
            results[i] = order[k - 1] + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            results[i] = order[n + k] + 1;
        }
        delete[] survivors;
        delete[] order;
    }
    for (long long int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        printf("%llu\n", results[i]);
    }
    delete[] results;
    return 0;
}
```

My inputs are: 
1 
1111111111 
-1

I am getting an exeption:

```
std::bad_array_new_length for large numbers
```

At line:

```
survivors = new unsigned long long[n];
```

How should I fix it that it wont show for such large numbers?

So far I tried all numeric types of n -> long long int, unsigned long and so on but everytime I was failing. Or maybe there is no way around that?

Comment: `new/delete` is not C.

Comment: if `n` is `1111111111`, then assuming `unsigned long long` is 8 bytes, then `new unsigned long long[n];` is allocating almost 9 gigabytes. Just to be sure, do you have that much free memory? If not, to fix it, buy more memory. What system are you running the code on? Is the system 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: @KamilCuk with virtual memory it shouldn't matter if you don't have enough physical memory.  What might matter is if you're compiling in 32-bit or 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I fix it that it wont show for such large numbers?

- Run the program on a 64 bit CPU.
- Use a 64 bit operating system.
- Compile the program in 64 bit mode.
- Install sufficient amount of memory. That array alone uses over 8 gigabytes.
- Configure operating system to allow that much memory be allocated for the process.

---

P.S. Avoid owning bare pointers. In this case, I recommend using a RAII container such as `std::vector`.